# How to update a column with calculation

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this trouble in sql. Like I want to make calculation first before it update. for example, I have formula to declare first, like this m = y/x then another formula for update the other column. I will make sample code for C++ but I want it in SQL.

```
int m, x, y, xn;
main()
{
m = y/x;
xn = (4.5*m/(POWER((1+m*m),0.5)))+y;
}
```

Thankyou for answering.

Comment: Can you provide the SQL-Table, you want to work with?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff

I want to add new column for my table and update it at the same time. For example, let's assume that I already add another column, I want to put values in that column through the result of 2 calculation (Example formula: First, m = y/x then YN = (4.5*m/(POWER((1+m*m),0.5)))+y;) the result of that YN will be the values I want to update in my added table. I hope I made myself clear. Thankyou for the response :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general the SQL equivalent of a variable is a column from a subquery:

```
with sometable (x, y) as (select 3, 15 from dual)
--
select x, y, m
from   ( select x, y, y/x as m
         from   sometable );

         X          Y          M
---------- ---------- ----------
         3         15          5
```

(I've used an inline view, but it could also be expressed as a `WITH` clause.)

In Oracle 12c you can also declare PL/SQL functions inline and code whatever calculations you like.

Comment: I want to add new column for my table and update it at the same time. For example, let's assume that I already add another column, I want to put values in that column through the result of 2 calculation (Example formula: First, m = y/x then YN = (4.5*m/(POWER((1+m*m),0.5)))+y;) the result of that YN will be the values I want to update in my added table. I hope I made myself clear. Thankyou for the

Comment: You can update an inline view e.g. `update (select x, y, y/x as m from t) set y = m;` I'll add this to my answer when I get a minute.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        declare @M int; 
        declare @x int, @y int, @xn int;
        SET @M= @y/@x;
        SET @xn = (4.5*@m/(POWER((1+@m*@m),0.5)))+@y;
        SELECT @xn AS Result1;
```